# Run rq command on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, redis, worker

I am trying to run the command "rq worker" on ubuntu to run a redis queue worker process for a web application

I already installed rq using pip3 install rq. However when I try to run the command on the Terminal it just tells me rq: command not found.

Does anybody know how to install the rq command on ubuntu 17.10??

thanks in advance

Comment: Logout - login?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed, it seems it was because I installed rq using pip without sudo.

I want this to remain documented for anybody else that is having a hard time:

If you install something using pip on linux but you don't use sudo you won't be able to use it on bash.

The correct way to install it and be able to use it on bash is

pip install rq

This applies to all of pip packages

Peace out

Comment: A better option, if using venv's, just install within the venv (no sudo required) and the executable will be in `~/venv/bin`; if you do something like: `python3 -m venv ~/venv && . venv/bin/activate && pip install rq && rq worker`.  This works because `venv/bin` is added to the `$PATH` environment variable, variable which can then be proven by executing: `echo $PATH && decativate && echo $PATH`.